# Showing a UIWebView in Cocos2d 2.x project

Tags: uiwebview, cocos2d-iphone

I'd like to display a UIWebView within a CCLayer for a Cocos2d 2.x project. I found the CCUIViewWrapper, but didn't get it to work with 2.x.

I don't really care about handling rotation and animation. I just wan't to display content from a web page on layer and also have a sprite to be able to go back to the previous scene.

Please help!

// Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use new version 2.0 features (I'm not using them myself at this point), then you can mix UIViews with Cocos by simply adding other views to your root view controller. After all, Cocos is itself a single view on the controller (if that's how you have it set up), and just add another view.

You can then easily tell the view controller to show the other UIViews by using the NSNotificationCenter, which I recommend in general over trying to communicate with the view controller from the Cocos layer.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please show me with code how to do this?

Comment: look at an empty Cocos project and study the viewcontroller.m; note how the Cocos view is set up as its own view. All you need to do is add another view using `addSubview` to `viewcontroller.view`